# determining absolute or conditional convergence using limit comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I'm currently learning determining absolute or conditional convergence on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/ic-series/ic-absolute-conditional/v/conditional-and-absolute-convergence).

One of the exercise question is

[image]

The answer provided is

[image]

I don't understand how the sum function does not converge by using the LIMIT COMPARISON TEST, I must be missing some of the required knowledge (specifically, the reason why limit comparison test can be used to prove the sum function does not converge), can someone please help me fill in the gap?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you don't understand? Have you tried working through the details of the limit comparison test in this example?

Comment: to be more specific, I dont understand the reason why limit comparison test can be used to prove the sum function does not converge.

Comment: There are many resources online that give a detailed proof of the limit comparison test. The basic intuition is that the quantity $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ tells you how many times larger the terms of $a_n$ are than the terms of $b_n$ (in the limit). If, for example, we get $1$ from this limit, then $a_n$ and $b_n$ have very similar rates of decay, and so they will either both converge or both diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
$$\lim_n \frac{\frac{n}{n^2+1}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_n \frac{n^2}{n^2+1} = 1,$$
which implies that $\sum_n \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ either both converge or both diverge (by the limit comparison test). Since we know that $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, it follows that $\sum_n \frac{n}{n^2+1}$ diverges.

The limit comparison test can be applied (as above) since, for all $n$, we have $\frac{n}{n^2+1} \geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{n} > 0$.